# how to find a number of occurence of a character in a string

Tags: php

I am searching for a function in PHP to return the number of occurence of a character in a string.

Inputing those parameters "hello world", 'o' would return 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`substr_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) is your friend

```
var_dump( substr_count("hello world", 'o') );
```

*note*:
this would also work since `substr_count` search for sub string

```
var_dump( substr_count("hello world", 'hello') );
```

Comment: LOL... I guess a short question deserves a short answer. :)

Comment: I suppose! just afraid if it's a homework but anyway that's not really like I have made a lot!

Comment: +1 for the right answer. And an imaginary +1 for answering even though you thought it was homework :)

Comment: @murugan: your textbox is inside a `<form>` if the `method` is get `$_GET['yourtextboxname']`, if the method is post `$_POST['yourtextboxname']`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `strlen()` of the string and the, a `str_replace()` with the desired char. Then you get the `strlen()` of that truncated string, the difference between lens is the char count =)

Something like this:

```
function count_char_occurence($haystack,$needle){
   $len = strlen($haystack);
   $len2 = strlen(str_replace($needle, '', $haystack));
   return $len - $len2;
}
```

with that speudo algorithm

```
print len("hello world")  : You get 11

a = replace("","o","hello world") : You get "hell wrld"

print len(a) : You get a 9
```

Then 11 - 9 = 2. That is your char count.

Answer (score 0):

Including it in a form would give this:

```
<form action="" method=post>
Give ur String: <input type="text" name="str" value="<? echo $_POST["str"]; ?>"/>
Search What Char: <input type="text" name="x" value="<? echo $_POST["x"]; ?>"/>

<input value="submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo substr_count($_POST["str"], $_POST['x'] );
}
?>
```